# oozie import my own modules in Python

Tags: python, oozie

I'm a newbie in Oozie. In **main.py**, I need to import my own modules **MY_CLASS.py** which is uploaded to the same HDFS path as main.py.

```
from MY_CLASS import my_class_1

def main():
    x = my_class_1()
    ...
```

There was an error in oozie saying *ImportError: No module named MY_CLASS*. Whereas it works perfectly on local.

I've also tried to create a folder in HDFS, put MY_CLASS.py in it together with a __init__.py , so that the folder can be recognized as a package. However `from folder.MY_CLASS import *` doesn't work for me neither in oozie.

Does anyone knows how to achieve this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the anwser. Just need to add `export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`.